# How to backup and restore gradle

Tags: gradle

I have gradle, and scala project. I want to move my project to another computer. That is, I would like to backup all gradle settings, libraries and restore them so that I can use them in another comp. Now, I have to install gradle and download all libraries again. Is there any way to move locally without needing to download.

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Why do you bother about downloading the libraries again anyways? Gradle Wrapper also would be a good hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the build uses libraries from Maven or Ivy repositories, you'll have to let Gradle download them again. (There isn't currently a reliable way to transfer the Gradle dependency cache between computers.) Assuming the build doesn't reference any files outside the project directory (which hopefully is the case), what's left to transfer is the project directory (best via source control) and any personal `gradle.properties` or `init.gradle` that you might have in `~/.gradle`.

If you happen to work with a manual Gradle installation, you'll also have to transfer the Gradle installation directory and any changes you made to your environment (e.g. you might have put the `gradle` startup script on your `PATH`). Instead I recommend to switch to the [Gradle Wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

Comment: @Pieter: interesting. Why isn't it reliable to transfer the gradle dependency cache between computers? What makes a cache on oe computer different from a cache on a second computer?

Comment: Last time I checked, some binary cache metadata contained absolute paths.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. We don't have access to the companies LAN and have to use our smart phones for the internet access. When I checked out the project the first time, we simply copied the cache via usb stick to my computer and it worked. Because of that I assumed that it works in general. Good hint with the absolute paths!

Comment: If it works for you, then you are probably fine. Just keep in mind that it's not currently a supported feature. I'm pretty sure you'll find a JIRA for it though.